# SPD 2013 REST API: Passing multiple type properties in metadata for creating a list item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, rest, api

how can I define two type properties in one __metadata then pass them in one rest call (post) in designer?

For example, how can I pass 
SP.Data.ProjectPolicyItemListItem and SP.FieldUrlValue in one call so that I can post to primitive and non-primitive data type fields at the simultaneously to a list item?

Answer (score -1):

Found my answer here in this site:
http://www.sharepointsiren.com/2015/01/sharepoint-designer-2013-rest-api-set.html?m=1